# Restore dependencies only with deps.json in .NET Core 2 app

Tags: .net, dependencies, .net-core, dotnet-cli

How to download all dependencies defined in dependency manifest file (*.deps.json) without the project (solution)? Like "self-contained deployment (SCD)" does this with `dotnet publish`, but manually on target server.

Comment: The answer is here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8679 It's not possible, the solution is to copy everything